# How to delete directory using java after uploading files to Remote Server?

Tags: java, ftp-client

My problem is need to transfer files from one remote server to another remote server (may be FTP/SFTP) but there is no direct method to transfer files from one remote server to another.

That's why I am downloading files from server to local temp.
After uploading to local to another server. After uploading I need to remove local temp folder but the files and the folder is not deleted.

Can you please help us in this regard?

My code is

```
    package FTPTransfer;


    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

    import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

    public class FtpToSftp
    {
         JSch sftp=null;
         ChannelSftp channelSftp=null;
         Channel channel=null;
         FTPClient ftp = null;
         Session session=null;     
         String SFTP_ROOT="/Mahesh/";
         String FTP_ROOT="/Mahesh/";
         String Local_Dir="./Temp/";
         int count=0;

public void ftpconnect(String host, String user, String pwd) throws Exception{

        ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

                int reply;
                ftp.connect(host);

                if(ftp.isConnected())
                    System.out.println("FTP Connected");

                reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                    throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
                }

                ftp.login(user, pwd);
                ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            }

            public void sftpconnect(String host, String user, String pwd) throws Exception{
                sftp=new JSch();
                session=sftp.getSession(user,host,22);
                session.setPassword(pwd);
                 java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                 config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                 session.setConfig(config); 
                session.connect();
                if(session.isConnected())
                    System.out.println("SFTP Session Connected");  
                channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                channel.connect();

                 if(channel.isConnected())
                      System.out.println("SFTP Channel Connected");
                    channelSftp=(ChannelSftp)channel;



            }

            public void downloadFromFTP()throws Exception {

                File f=new File(Local_Dir);
                if(!f.exists())
                f.mkdir();

                FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles(FTP_ROOT);  
                  count=0;
                  OutputStream outputStream=null;
                for (FTPFile fname : files) {  
                 if (fname.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {
                     System.out.println(fname.getName());

                     File downloadFile = new File(Local_Dir+ fname.getName());
                     outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
                     boolean success = ftp.retrieveFile(FTP_ROOT+fname.getName(), outputStream);
                     if(success)
                         count++;
                     else
                         downloadFile.delete();
                 }
                }

                if(count==files.length)
                    System.out.println("Files Downloaded Successfully");
                System.out.println("count:"+count+"files length:"+files.length);
                outputStream.close();

            }

            public void uploadToSFTP() throws Exception{

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;//0 based
                    String foldername=month+""+year+"/";
                    String fullDirPath=SFTP_ROOT+foldername;

                    SftpATTRS attrs=null;
                    try{
                    attrs=channelSftp.lstat(fullDirPath);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
                     if(attrs==null)
                     {
                    channelSftp.mkdir(fullDirPath);
                    channelSftp.cd(fullDirPath);
                     }

                count=0;
                File f1 = new File(Local_Dir);
                  File list[] = f1.listFiles();
                 for(File fname  : list) {
                       System.out.println(fname);    
                     channelSftp.put(fname+"", fullDirPath+fname.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE); 
                      }

                  if(count==f1.length())
                    System.out.println("Files Uploaded Successfully");



            }

       public FtpToSftp() throws Exception{


           System.out.println("Connecting to FTP");
           ftpconnect("10.219.28.110", "webteam", "web$123");
           System.out.println("Connecting to SFTP");
           sftpconnect("10.219.29.61","root" , "leo$123");

           downloadFromFTP();

           if(ftp.logout()){
               ftp.disconnect();
                System.out.println("FTP connection closed");
             }
           uploadToSFTP();
           channelSftp.disconnect();
               }

        public static final void main(String[] args) 
        {

            try{
                    FtpToSftp fs=new FtpToSftp();
                    File file=new File(fs.Local_Dir);
                   if(file.isDirectory())
                   {  
                       File[] files = file.listFiles();
                       for (File f : files)
                        {
                             String fname=f.getName();
                             boolean success=f.delete();  
                             if(success)
                                System.out.println(fname+" file deleted from local");
                        }       
                   }
                   if(file.delete())
                       System.out.println("Temp folder deleted from local");

                  }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } // end main


    }
```

Comment: When transferring files from SFTP Server to Another SFTP server the folder is deleted.When one server is FTP i am not able to delete files as well as folder.
Please give me solution/suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Apache FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) to do this and all other common commands needed with FTP.

**Example to delete a folder:**

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect(host, port);
client.login(loginname, password);
client.removeDirectory(directoryPathOnServer);
client.disconnect();
```

Comment: I am not able to transfer files directly that's why i am doing downloading to local from one server and uploading to another server.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code snippet that deletes all the contents of the directory and the directory itself..

```
private void deleteDirectory(String path,FTPClient ftpClient) throws Exception{
    FTPFile[] files=ftpClient.listFiles(path);
    if(files.length>0) {
        for (FTPFile ftpFile : files) {
            if(ftpFile.isDirectory()){
                logger.info("trying to delete directory "+path + "/" + ftpFile.getName());
                deleteDirectory(path + "/" + ftpFile.getName(), ftpClient);
            }
            else {
                String deleteFilePath = path + "/" + ftpFile.getName();
                logger.info("deleting file {}", deleteFilePath);
                ftpClient.deleteFile(deleteFilePath);
            }

        }
    }
        logger.info("deleting directory "+path);
        ftpClient.removeDirectory(path);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to delete an directory in your system**

This is an part of example:

```
File x=new File("C:\Users\satyamahesh\folder");
String[]entries = x.list();
for(String s: entries){
    File currentFile = new File(x.getPath(), s);
    currentFile.delete();
}
```

Then your folder is deleted.

**If you want test it success or don't success to download a folder**

Please test Ad Fundum's answer.

Comment: Please use the new I/O API called **NIO**, `File` is outdated.

Comment: File is not outdated. It's still part of the Java API.

Answer (score 0):

***Example to delete a folder:*** (@SatyaMahesh In this part your code is incorrect and this code used NIO is correct.):

```
File downloadFile = new File(Local_Dir+ fname.getName());
outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
boolean success = ftp.retrieveFile(FTP_ROOT+fname.getName(), outputStream);
if(success)
  count++;
else{
  Path path = Paths.get("data/subdir/logging-moved.properties");
  try {
    Files.delete(path);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    //deleting file failed
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Then your folder is deleted.

Comment: Please use the new I/O API called **NIO**, `File` is outdated.

Comment: You can use **File** in deleting some folders.

Comment: @Zabuza Actually, I know how to use NIO **Files.delete(), Files.createDirectory(), Paths.get()**. Alternatively, you can use File like **blah-blah-blah.delete()**. So your comment dosen't very make sense. In addition, Java 7 **is similar to Java 8**, do **alternatively your comment is not correct because I worked**, and you edit your comment like add **but alternatively this is correct** in bold text **NIO**'s right, delete your **_File_ is outdated**. You posting comment **like** this issue, don't post comments like an issue of this answer, something wrong with using **File**?